# Salesforce API access users' licenses

Tags: soql, rest-api, user, licenses

As part of a task, I need to look into Salesforce to grab users and find what licenses they are using (all through SOQL so far, with Oauth authentication).

As part of my research, I looked up the [`UserLicense`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm) object, but the **`LicenseDefinitionKey`** field is really not that helpful (values don't reflect proper license split or names).

Is there any other object I should be looking at which may contain proper licenses? I don't think I am the only one around looking for that.

Edit from comments:

What I get from field **LicenseDefinitionKey**:

- AUL: corresponds to the Salesforce Platform user license
- AUL1: corresponds to the Salesforce Platform One user license
- SFDC: corresponds to the Full CRM user license

What I would like to find: proper licenses as per Salesforce "**Company Information**":

- [image: Company info]

Comment: Can you share on what difference you see?

Comment: "the LicenseDefinitionKey field is really not that helpful (**values don't reflect proper license split or names**)". Can you add some clarification on what you are expecting to see beyond what the LicenseDefinitionKey provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the more common names to match up with the Company Information UI using SOQL.

```
Select Id, Name, LicenseDefinitionKey from UserLicense
```

[image: UserLicense LicenseDefinitionKey field]

If you want to start grouping by UserLicense type start with:

```
Select Id,Name, Profile.UserLicense.Name,Profile.UserLicense.Id  from User
```

Then start grouping by UserLicense:

```
Select Profile.UserLicense.Name, Count(Id)  from User group by Profile.UserLicense.Name
```

---

> How can we also get a "SFDC" UserLicense breakdown like on the Company Info screen "Feature Licenses" section?

I believe these are the [`User.UserPermissions*`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) fields.  E.g. UserPermissionsOfflineUser is "Indicates whether the user is enabled to use Offline Edition (true) or not (false). Label is Offline User."

[image]

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Doing this map does give me the map between users and UserLicense, but how what is the mapping between LicenseDefinitionKey and "User License" found in Company Info screen? there is no 1 to 1 match between the 2

Comment: How can we also get a "SFDC" UserLicense breakdown like on the Company Info screen "Feature Licenses" section? Thanks!

Comment: Each UserLicense has a unique LicenseDefinitionKey. Or at least that has been my finding. The Feature Licenses appear on the User with the UserPermissions* fields.